# Why does this element animate backwards?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am learning about CSS animations and I'm a little stuck on something. I've got things mostly working but the first balloon is going backwards first and I do not understand why. I've tried a whole lot of different things, like changing the position translate with no success. Any thoughts? The class of the first balloon I am referring to is initialBalloon.

```css
html {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after { /* allow all elements to inherit box-sizing */
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html, body { 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 overflow:hidden; 
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}


.BalloonContainer {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.initialBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  /* moves initial position before animating */
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  top: 150px;
  animation: moveFirst 5s linear .2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  width: 150px;
}

.firstBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  top: 150px;
  animation: move 5s linear 5s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.secondBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  top: 200px;
  animation: move 8s linear 0s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.thirdBalloon {
  top: 250px;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 11s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-30vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
  50% {
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="BalloonContainer">
  <div class="initialBalloon swingimage">
   <svg id="Balloon_1" data-name="Balloon_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_1p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_1" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_1" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="firstBalloon swingimage">
   <svg id="Balloon_2" data-name="Balloon_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_2p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_2" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_2" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="secondBalloon swingimage">
   <svg id="Balloon_3" data-name="Balloon_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_3p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_3" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_3" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thirdBalloon swingimage">
   <svg id="Balloon_4" data-name="Balloon_4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_4p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_4" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_4" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be going from `50vw` to `0vw` then to `100vw`. Hence why it looks to be going backwards.

Adding `translateX(75vw)` (half way intbetween 50 and 100) to the `50%` mark for the `moveFirst` animation class worked for me.

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(75vw) rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Why didn't I think of that. Grrrr! Thanks for taking the time, sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Glad it all worked out. Would be awesome if you could mark this as the accepted answer too. :)

Comment: sorry about that. Thought I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this changed example

just changed

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(70vw) rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}
```

```css
html {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after { /* allow all elements to inherit box-sizing */
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html, body { 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 overflow:hidden; 
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}


.BalloonContainer {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.initialBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  /* moves initial position before animating */
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  top: 150px;
  animation: moveFirst 5s linear .2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  width: 150px;
}

.firstBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  top: 150px;
  animation: move 5s linear 5s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.secondBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  top: 200px;
  animation: move 8s linear 0s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.thirdBalloon {
  top: 250px;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 11s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-30vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
  50% {
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
 transform: translateX(70vw) rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="BalloonContainer">
  <div class="initialBalloon swingimage">
   <svg id="Balloon_1" data-name="Balloon_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_1p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_1" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_1" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
 </div>
```